# Find files based on siblings

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

Consider this directory:

```
thingsToThinkAbout/
    thing1.txt
    thing2.txt
    thing2.txt.thoughts.txt
    thing3.txt
    thing7.txt.thoughts.txt
```

With bash `find` I can look for the things (`find . -name "thing*.txt"`), the thoughts (`find . -name "thing*.txt.thoughts.txt"`) or both (`find . -name "*.txt"`), but can I use the command to search based on *siblings* as well?

In my example, I did not think about `thing1.txt` and `thing3.txt`, and I have some thoughts about a "thing 7", which doesn't exist. To find those, I would have to look for files X who do not have siblings named Y. How could this be done?

Obviously, I could write a complete script with `if`s, but is that needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Note

> With bash `find` I can look for the things (`find . -name "thing*.txt"`)

Have you tried this? This will find thoughts as well. The following `find` invocation excludes them:

```
find . -name "thing*.txt" ! -name "*.thoughts.txt"
```

---

#### Answer

To find things without thoughts you can use `-exec` (or `-execdir`) as a test. It succeeds if the invoked command returns exit status of `0`. In this case the command is `test`:

```
find . -name "thing*.txt" ! -name "*.thoughts.txt" -exec test ! -e "{}.thoughts.txt" \; -print
```

As you can see it's quite easy to add a string to the name (`"{}.thoughts.txt"`). To find thoughts without things you basically do the same, but you need to remove some string; it's not so easy. An extra shell can do this:

```
find . -name "thing*.txt.thoughts.txt" -exec sh -c 'test ! -e "${1%.thoughts.txt}"' sh {} \; -print
```

`${1%.thoughts.txt}` returns `$1` with `.thoughts.txt` removed from the very end. We check if this file doesn't exist.

Note `find … -exec test …` executes the `test` executable, while `sh -c 'test …'` uses the `test` builtin of `sh`. These are not the same, it shouldn't matter in this case though.